# Force JAXB to ignore getters/setters on 3rd-party class file

Tags: java, jaxb

### Background

I have a class in a JAR file called Attachment. The important parts of the definition are below.

```
public class Attachment
{
    public List<Media> media;

    public List<Media> getMedia()
    {
        return this.media;
    }

    public void setMedia(List<Media> media)
    {
        this.media = media;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to use [JAXB-impl 2.1.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.3) to deserialize this with the following code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Attachment.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);
Attachment attachment = (Attachment) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

However, this gives me the following error (snipped for brevity)

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 
1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Class has two properties of the same name "media"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.thirdparty.Attachment.getMedia()
            ...
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.util.List com.thirdparty.Attachment.media
            ...
```

I understand that the issue is that, by default, JAXB will use an access type of [PUBLIC_MEMBER](https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ed/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType.html#PUBLIC_MEMBER), which is defined as:

> Every public getter/setter pair and every public field will be automatically bound to XML, unless annotated by XmlTransient.

### Question

So, my question is, how can I tell JAXB to ignore the field and just use the getter/setter. Note that I would prefer it this way round, as there are a number of private fields that I would need to ignore (I believe that Attachment has been set public in error in fact).

Comment: Load time weaving and applying XmlTransient as necessary might be an idea, but that's only a guess

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear - this is a 3rd party class I have no control over - I can't edit it to apply attributes or similar. Note also that the 3rd party uses JAXB to do their serialization, hence why I want to use it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Annox](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/JAXB+User+Guide).It looks to have what you need.

*JAXB reference implementation can be configured with a special annotation reader which may implement a different strategy for reading annotations. Annox takes advantage of this feature and implements an annotation reader which can load JAXB annotations from XML.*

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the E[**clipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

MOXy offers an external mapping document extension to support 3rd party classes.

**Sample Mapping Document**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="blog.bindingfile">
    <xml-schema
        namespace="http://www.example.com/customer"
        element-form-default="QUALIFIED"/>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <xml-type prop-order="firstName lastName address phoneNumbers"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="firstName" name="first-name"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="lastName" name="last-name"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="phoneNumbers" name="phone-number"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="PhoneNumber">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="type"/>
                <xml-value java-attribute="number"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Bootstrapping from External Mapping Document**

Below is an example of how you create the `JAXBContext`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "blog/bindingfile/binding.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("blog.bindingfile", Customer.class.getClassLoader() , properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/blog/bindingfile/input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: I've found Moxy fantastic any time I've used it (good job). I never knew I could do this so thank you.